# Triple boot with Ubuntu, Windows 10 and Kali - no system will boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 16.10, kali

Here's is my info link from using the boot-repair; it could not fix my problem.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/23958241/

Neither Windows, Ubuntu nor Kali Linux will load at all.
I got this error message when I boot up my computer

```
0xc000000f
```

Comment: What *do you see* on powerup exactly?

Comment: 0xc000000f is a Windows error that just means there's something wrong with the Windows bootloader. And all the EXT4 partitions failed to mount. Did this setup ever worked? If so what did you do prior to it not booting?

Comment: @CelticWarrior well when I correct that windows error right. I use my windows disc to repair my startup. But I can't load Ubuntu or my kali Linux at all afterwards.

Comment: Correcting Windows boot doesn't prevent EXT4 partitions from mounting. Did this setup **ever** worked? (new question) If so, when you noticed Windows wasn't booting, could you still boot Ubuntu? Or was it after correcting Windows? What did you do exactly? Trying to establish a timeline in order to (eventually) understand what might have happened.

Comment: @CelticWarrior windows never properly load up at all before or after I use the boot-repair program.

Comment: Boot-repair is not for correcting Windows (it may in certain cases but that's not the purpose). You can boot Ubuntu and try to reinstall. All done properly you should end up with a functional dual boot. Adding a third OS complicates thing a little bit because the last one installed will try to take over Grub. Windows and Kali are off-topic here.

Comment: @CelticWarrior How is windows and Kali Linux is off topic here? I see other posts about it here for dual boots. well I try to reinstall it but still my windows os will not load.

Comment: For dual (or multiple)boots of course, we can help with that. However do not expect us to give you instructions on how to recover your Windows and/or install Kali or whatever else that isn't Ubuntu or official derivatives. Assuming you already have Windows booting, reinstalling Ubuntu will provide the dual boot capability. Do you need help installing . Ubuntu? Not likely because you already installed Ubuntu and Kali. So, what else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53541/discussion-between-james-marsh-and-celticwarrior).